# Atributo HREF no funciona

Tags: html

Estoy utilizando la etiqueta `href` así:

```html
<a href="Inicio.html">ini</a>
```

Pero no me habilita el vínculo en el archivo index. No entiendo por qué sucede esto.

---

En mi página, lo tengo así:

```html
<section>
  <text-aling>
    <center> <img src="/recursos/logo1.jpeg" alt="image" heigth="250" width="250"></center>
  </text-aling>
</section>

<nav>
  <a href="Inicio.html">Inicio</a>
</nav>

<video src="recursos/presentacion.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay loop></video>
```

y no me funciona el hipervínculo allí. Pero más abajo lo tengo de este otro modo y sí funciona correctamente:

```html
<p class="Promociones">Promociones</p>
<div class="imgprom3">
  <img src="/recursos/vale, paula.jpeg" alt="image" heigth=450 width="450"><br>
  <a href="Servicios.html">CANCUN</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Andres, cuando dices que no funciona, ¿a qué te refieres? ¿Cuando pulsas el enlace te va a una página que no es? ¿Te aparece un error 404? ¿No hace nada? Complete el [tour] y lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y de ese modo ganarás tu primera medalla en el sitio.

Comment: cuando me refiero a que no funciona, es cuando ejecuto el index, no habilita la palabra INI como un hipervínculo hacia la hoja INICIO.HTML.

Comment: ¿ni siquiera lo hace un vinculo?¿o si lo hace un vinculo pero no a la hoja de inicio.html? Tal y como está descrito el problema, no queda claro. Y el código está correcto. Hace falta más información o la pregunta acabará cerrada como "no se puede reproducir" (he puesto el código como ejecutable y se ve cómo es un enlace que va a Inicio.html)

Comment: lo tengo asi; <body>
    <section><text-aling><center> <img src="/recursos/logo1.jpeg" alt="image"heigth="250" width="250" ></center></text-aling></section>
    <nav>
       <a href="Inicio.html">Inicio</a>
    </nav>

    <video 
        src="recursos/presentacion.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay loop>
    </video>, no me funciona el hipervínculo allí, pero mas abajo lo tengo asi; <p class="Promociones">Promociones</p><div class="imgprom3"><img src="/recursos/vale, paula.jpeg" alt="image"heigth=450 width="450"><br><a href="Servicios.html">CANCUN</a></div> alli si funciona correctamente.

Comment: Aún no aclaras cómo no funciona, y esa es la parte más importante para poder decirte cuál es el fallo. Aparte, ¿el fichero enlazado que falla se llama Inicio.html o inicio.html en tu directorio?

Comment: He editado la pregunta para añadir el código que has puesto en el comentario. Lo he hecho ejecutable y se puede ver que el enlace se muestra correctamente y apunta al lugar que se indica en el atributo `href`. Necesitamos más información para poder ayudarte.